# loading image while loading a gridview on runtime

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I'm looking for a solution to my problem for two days and I didn't find anything that can help.  I have two page : page 1 and page 2
Page1 contains parameters that will be send to page2 and a button "Create"
Page2 contains the `GridView` and on `page_load` I have

```
GetParameters() ;   // extract parameters
PrepareParameters(); // prepare local variable 
DataTable dt = CreateDataTable(); // create the BoundField/Columns based on prepared local variables
myGridView.DataSource = dt;
myGridView.DataBind();
```

My problem is that the method `PrepareParameters()` takes time due to the huge amount of data even though it's optimized. When I click on "Create" button the browser doesn't move to page2 but instead it doesn't respond and stay in page1 and the user does not know what happens.
So I'm wondering how to redirect the browser to page2 and show to the user a loading animation on the grid place until the `PrepareParameters()` finish processing data and display the `GridView` once finished?
Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript to do that. Get any loader image you prefer, there are many available on net, [google it](http://www.google.co.in/search?q=ajax%20loader%20image&hl=en&prmd=imvns&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=zBPSTtWlIMrorAev_OjVDA&ved=0CCUQsAQ&biw=1366&bih=667&sei=0BPSToz0CcXKrAfXj6n0DA)

put this image top/bottom of grid, assign some id to it and set default property Visible = false.
Now on button click call javascript where you make this image visible.

Sample code

```
    <html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">

function Loading() {
  document.getelemanebyId('Img').visibility = visible;
} 
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form action="" method="POST" id="myForm">

//Gridview control here
<img id="Img" src="give image file path" runat="server" visible="false"/>
<button name="Create" onClientClick="Loading();" runat="server" >

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Pramodtech, Thank you for your reply. Actually i saw this solution everywhere and I think it does not fit my problem but nevertheless i gave it a try and does not work. The browser remains on page1 until the browser is finished.

Comment: yes browser will remain on same page only thing is loading image will displayed so that user will not be confused on what is happening. Other thing you can do is, keep grid in div and hide this grid using above mentioned javascript. I don't think you can redirect to next page until operation from page 1 is over.

Comment: but PrepareParameters() is a method in page2 and the grid too?